# Android context after process gets killed

Tags: android

I want to get the context after my app process is killed so that I can  display a  Toast. Requirement is that if user does not activates the location , I want to show a toast and kill all processes. How can I get a context in this situation ?

Comment: Why would you kill the process?  That's very unusual to do in Android, do you mean kill the Activity?  If you actually kill the process there is no Context, because there's no app running.

Comment: Hmm , actually i mean kill all the program but i understand. What can i do when user try to use program without location. Program is useless without it.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended that you simply display a message that tells the user that location services are required for you to use the application. You will not be able to display a Toast message if you kill the process.